# A romantic evening - what to drink?

Tags: wine, cider

OK, I want to create a romantic evening - everything is organized except for the perfect beverage!  For various reasons, champagne is out, so is any type of wine or beer or cider.  Thus the question, apart from all the above, what can I serve for my romantic evening?

Comment: How about what your companion prefers?

Comment: Ah, well that is why I put the no can't have this that and the other requirements - for various reasons certain things are out, but I want it to be a surprise.  On the whole though, mr dougal can drink anything except red wine.  It's dougal who can't drink the other stuff, so I want us both to enjoy something together and not have to resort to two different things, as is normal.  Any suggestions - I'm fairly open to anything (alcoholic)!

Comment: What sort of engagement are we talking here? Is this a blind date? Fancy, aged red wine for good first impression type deal? Or, is this for your main squeeze? Sex on the Beach would be an option type deal?

Comment: I like the sex on the beach idea!  Especially as we live on a boat and beaches are always near.  No we have been together since since - well - I am so old now I cant remember!  It's just a 'Hey let's be romantic 'cos I still sort of love you evening'.  OK OK you can all go and be sick now!

Comment: @dougal3.0.0 are you somewhere that you could get sparkling mead or is it off the list?

Comment: Thanks for the input, but that too is off the list - life can be a right pain in the $%^& at times!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most romantic thing is to conform to the desires of your companion. It sounds like there are specific problems with sparkling and red wine. Personally as much as I like beer, I don't think it is "romantic" with the possible exception of a Belgium Tripel. These taste great, are surprisingly alcoholic and look neat served in the appropriate glass (a large wine glass may suffice). What I do think might be fun is a good French rose (a sparkling rose is really romantic, but out). Otherwise investigate cocktails. Unfortunately, I not much of a cocktail guy so I don't have any suggestions. Googling "romantic cocktails" provides a lot of hits.

Comment: ah ha, any suggestions?

Comment: @dougal3.0.0  Please see my edits including a beer suggestion.

Comment: Sadly any beer, even the Belgium stuff is out...  And I agree, a 'posh' beer in a large stemmed glass does look nice.  I'm thinking of going all out for a super sonic 'Del boy' type cocktail though just for a laugh (complete with umbrella!).

Comment: @dougal3.0.0  oh well, you did ask for a beer suggestion. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what the restrictions are so I have to guess.

So how about highballs/longdrinks? If you are easy on the spirits it should be possible to drink them as beverages.

What might be a nice companion to food (depends on the food and your taste) as it's not too sweet and not to much alcohol: Lillet (white vermouth) and Wild Berry (Schweppes).

Margaritas are also common during dinner, but that might be a problem as you're on a boat.

Coke & rum, vodka & orange-juice, gin & tonic might also work.